# Making non-asp table invisible in behind-code

Tags: c#, webforms, html-table, code-behind, visible

I'm working with code someone else has written that I cannot change too much for now.

It has a table defined in the html, something like this:

```
<table id="tblResult">
   some stuff defined in here.
</table>
```

I would like to use the behind code to make this table and all its contents invisible, but I notice I can't address the table directly as tblResult.visible in the code behind.  This makes sense to me, since this is not an asp object.  Simply changing this to an asp:table doesn't work, as there's some stuff going on inside that table I prefer not to mess with. Is it possible to address that table and set visibility to false from the behindcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it into a `<asp:PlaceHolder>` amd then toggle the placeholder visibility.

Comment: Adding a runat=server attribute can change the generated id attribute in the client.

Answer (score 1):

Add `runat='server'` to the tag.  The other thing you can do is wrap it around a server side tag of div, panel, etc and set them to `visible='false'`  Something to this effect:

```
<div id='myDiv' runat='server'>
 <table id="tblResult">
   //stuff
 </table>
</div>
```

Then in your code-behind:

`this.myDiv.Visible=False;`

This will now ensure your table is not visible.  Again you can use div's, panels (which are just divs really), literals, placeholders, etc.

Comment: Inserting a div he can cause a script/style crash. I think the best solution in this cases is to use a Placeholder as I've said.

Comment: Not sure about a crash, I mentioned he could use various tags.  The point is he needs to access code behind for a specific object, all of those allow you to.  The actual most simple way to do that is to just add runat='server' on his current table.  He doesn't even need to use a glorified ASP.net table or a placeholder at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a `Literal`:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" Visible="False">
<table> ... </table>
</asp:Literal>
```